# JQuery UI Autocomplete - Unable to load object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, autocomplete

I am trying to get autocomplete working working with JQuery UI, but I am having trouble when I try and pass in a label & value object.

```
        var people = [];
        var test = new Array();
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $.each(obj.data, function(i,person){
                people[people.length] = {
                        label: person.id,
                        value: person.name
                };
                test.push(person.name);
        });

        $("#friend").autocomplete({
                source: test,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    alert(ui.item.id);
                }
        });
```

When I use the 'test' array it is working correctly, but when I try and use the people object nothing seems to be working, an no JS errors either.

What am I missing?

Comment: As in when I use the test array, and start typing in the box I get the list of names. But when I use the people object I don't get anything....

Comment: Why are you using different array methods in each case?  `[]` vs `new Array()` and `person[person.length]` vs `.push()`?

Comment: I feel like something's missing in the code example.

Comment: Is your selector correct? do you have an `input id="friend"` on the page?

Comment: Works for me ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/8mB3U/)). Are you sure you put all your code here ?

Comment: @DidierGhys, yours works because your ids and values are similar.  His doesn't work I assume, because his ids are numbers or something dissimilar from his names.  He needs to simply reverse them I believe.  See my answer below.

Comment: @JeffB. Why would it matter the ID is int or string ? ([see here](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/fwes4/))

Comment: @DidierGhys, it doesn't matter.  The point is that they are backwards.  If you type "lolo" in your second example, you won't get autocomplete because it is being loaded as the id and not the value.  Your first example masked this because the id/values were similar.

Comment: Wow. Damn you were smart to understand that it was **that** that was not *working*... Respect :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading your people object backwards.  Autocomplete works on the `label`, not the `value`, so you are autocompleting on your id instead of the name.

`label` will be the text that is autocomplete uses to match, and `value` is what is returned when you choose it.

Simply reverse them, and it will work:

```
 people[people.length] = {
     label: person.name,
     value: person.id
 };
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qmmms/1/

Comment: Yes, and as he said, the array works, but the object doesn't.  This is why his object isn't working like he expects.

Comment: Yes you are correct, only noticed when jornare posted their answer above. Silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
people.push({value:person.id,label:person.name});
```

Like this:

```
var people = []; 
var obj = {data:[{id:1,name:"Adam"},{id:2,name:"Eve"}]};
$.each(obj.data, function(i,person){ 
        people.push( { 
                label: person.name, 
                value: person.id 
        }); 
}); 
$("#friend").autocomplete({ 
        source: people, 
        select: function(event, ui) { 
            alert(ui.item.name); 
        } 
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Turns out I had the label and value the wrong way round, and so what I was looking for wasn't showing but when I searched for IDs instead, the list popped up. Many Thanks!